# Azure Function Java : The binding type(s) blobTrigger are not registered

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

Have created a blob trigger in java by following [functions-reference-java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java). The trigger works locally, however in the portal it says
Error: The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered.

Have followed these instructions to update the [azure-function-core](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#updating-function-app-targeting-java)

My Function app details:

- Runtime version: 2.0.12246.0 (~2)
- Plaftform: 64-bit

How to get the extensions installed ?

[Function app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j64Ha.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself. `extensions.csproj` was missing from my pipeline.

I manually added it via the portal and ran the following in the kudu prompt.

```
dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget
```